# How to unlock my Mac in iCloud?

Tags: mac, icloud, unlock

I don't know how this happened but my Mac was locked; now when I go to **iCloud -> Find my Mac** I found my Mac with locked status.
The problem that I don't know the pin code to unlock it.

Is there any way to unlock it remotely from the iCloud account or using trick to remove the lock.

So each time I start my Mac, it tell me to wait 60min before trying again, one count down reach zero I get :

> incorrect code, please try again

Instead of getting the input pin screen 
[image: error screen]

Comment: Call Apple support.

Comment: They will ask for purchase proof which I don't have.

Comment: If the Mac is associated with your Apple ID, and you can prove that it's your Apple ID then you should be fine.

Comment: Yeah it's associated with my Appel ID (iCloud account ) but how to prove that ID is my id

Comment: [Apple ID Temporary Support PIN](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT202650)

Comment: @ecnepsnai Please check my update, also the EFI is locked and I'had never set lock on it this the first time open the EFI but it's protected with password